# Multiple CSS styles on a html button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button for a message system to show an orange dot if there's a new message. However, i can't quite get it working. Is it possible?

Here's the button

```
<input type="button" value="Messages &bull;" />​
```

And the button on jsFiddle if anyone feels like trying out :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/ePA47/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `button` element instead.

```
<button type="button">
   Messages <span style="color: orange;">&bull;</span>
</button>
```

Of course, don't add your stylings inline. I just did for this example's sake.

You could also add a class to the `button` such as `new-messages` and then do...

```
button.new-messages:after {
    content: "•";
    color: orange;
}
```

Just keep in mind the latter won't work in older IEs.

Comment: This works pretty well. Why would it be wrong to add stylings inline?

Comment: @PatrickReck It's presentational information, so it should live in the presentational layer (the CSS) where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<button>` instead of `<input>` since it has child elements which you can style.

Answer (score 0):

To add an orange dot to your button, I would recommend using a `background-image`. This will give you the ability to design the dot however you wish, and not be constrained by font types.

It's also better for accessibility if the orange dot is added as a background image, as this is not content.

```
<input type="button" value="Messages" class="newmessage" />​​​​​​

​.newmessage
{
    background-image:url('http://img859.imageshack.us/img859/9611/orangedot.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:25px;
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ePA47/3/
​

Answer (score 0):

As per the question heading, the following will help to add multiple styles in a single style tag

```
<button type="button" style= "margin-top : 20px; border-radius: 15px" 
class="btn btn-primary">View Full Profile
</button>
```